# How to make navbar items a fixed width in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to produce a Navbar similar to the one on this page :

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0375140

I am using Bootstrap 3 and can create the top corner rounded boxes with slight gradient at bottom easy enough.

The thing I am struggling with is that the menu items in the navbar on that example are all the same width regardless of how wide the text in them is.

I am scratching my head trying to find out how that is done - And ideas much appreciated.

Comment: If you can't solve it with my answer above, would you please upload some of your code for me to assist you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add css width property to all elements in the navbar.

Assuming your navbar is something like this:

```
<div id="myCustomNavbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You should add some style with CSS:

```
#myCustomNavbar > ul > li
{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Remember you can always right-click the element you are interested in (in the sample webpage), and click Inspect element. There you can see all html markup and CSS styles applicated to that element

Comment: I am feeling a bit sheepish now...  I thought I had tried applying a width but, obviously, I hadn't lol!   Thank you that works perfectly,  now I don't suppose you know how to change that width to 100% if the menu is displayed on mobile (IE: Hamburger menu) ?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #myCustomNavbar > ul > li {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}`

That should do it

(you could remove the !important from both styles if you want)

Comment: I had just tried that myself and it works great - thank you very much for all your help - much appreciated :)